# $this->getRequest()->isPost() return false

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm working on an existing code who the last developer have created a form but without using a "$form", and the code is:

```
 public function indexAction() {
    .......

    $objRequest = $this->getRequest();
    var_dump($objRequest->isPost())  ==> all time return false
    if ($objRequest->isPost()) {

    $postedData = $objRequest->getPost();
    $inputData = new Zend_Filter_Input($this->filters, $this->validators,
                        $objRequest->getPost());

        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if ($inputData->isValid()) {

   .....
```

and in the vie :

```
<?php $actionURL = $this->url(array(
'controller' => 'index',
'action'     => 'index',
'module'     => 'default',
));
?>

<form name="indexFormn" id="indexForm"  method="POST" action="<?php echo $actionURL; ?>">
<div class="AdminformDiv">
    <div class="errorbox">
        <?php
        if (!is_array($this->actionErrors)) {
            echo $this->actionErrors;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:700px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:128px">Amount</td>
                    <td colspan="2">$ <?php echo $this->price;?> USD<td     style="width:270px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

    .....
```

That means he don't use any form class but he do like the old php method but with zend,so all time he return false and I can't fix or detect where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem and found the solution after hours of searching. Check whether your opening and closing form tags are fulling enclosing the form. I accidentally forgot to remove an additional closing form tag that I previously put in the view file.

I'm not hundred percent sure how this affected my form but the additional closing form tag changed my method to 'get' even though I set it to post, thus when I hit submit, it would skip right passed the validation part.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The form has `method="GET"` - it's not a POST form, so that's why `isPost()` is returning false. Change that to `method="POST"` and it should be fine.

Comment: No Im really sorry I made a mistake,when I did test before posting here it was "post".So "get" or "post" it return in both case "false"?

Comment: If in the controller, above your existing var_dump, you temporarily add `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);`, what does that give you?

Comment: var_dump retur me `string(3) "GET"` yes very strange? but I'm sure it's "post" in my view??

Comment: Hard to debug this further with the info we have. Either the form you posted isn't the one being submitted, or the request method is being changed with javascript for some reason.

Comment: I understand but in tha same page I'm sure they are just one <form> and no javascript included?

Comment: I disactivate all javascript code related to form or something like that in my page but still var_dump return me "GET" that really get me crazy...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem derived from nginx config using zend:

The missing $args was not populating the query string:

I change:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

To:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

The question related [about this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/456948/135192) has a more detailed explanation about that. But basically:

> Unlike with rewrite, $args are not automatically preserved if the
>   fallback is not a named location. If you need args preserved, you must
>   do so explicitly: