# Data is not inserted into database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a form where user insert their basic details and after submitting form it will redirect on view page. I trying to submit it redirect on view page without inserting data into database. I debug my code of controller I come to know that $request = $this->getRequest(); code in $request I am getting GET [ 1 ] and post is empty and in if condition here used $this->getRequest()->isPost() to check whether that post is true or false. Please find screenshot of code of controller.

Controller function

```
public function addAction() {
    $captcha = new Zend_Session_Namespace('captcha');
    $captcha->captcha = session_id();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValidPartial($request->getPost())) {
            $dataform = $request->getPost();
            $alphabet = 
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
            $pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
            $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; 
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
                $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
                $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
            }
            $randomPassword = implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
            $dataform['password'] = $randomPassword;
            if ($dataform['vercode'] != $_SESSION["vercode"]) {
                $msg = "Please enter a correct code!";
                $this->view->assign('errorMessage', $msg);

                return FALSE;
            }
            if ($dataform['sessionCheck'] != $captcha->captcha) {
                $this->view->assign('errorMessage', CSRF_ATTACK);

                return FALSE;
            }
            if($dataform['name'] == 2 && $dataform['statename'] == 0){
                    $this->view->assign('errorMessage', 'Please select state 
             for the state officials!');
                    return;
                    }
                    $Contactusobj = new Application_Model_User;
                    $countdata = $Contactusobj- 
             >checkuserclient($dataform['username']);
                    $countemail = $Contactusobj- 
                  >checkemail($dataform['email']);
                    if(($countdata == 0)){
                    $match  = $Contactusobj->insertuserdetails($dataform);
                    $description = 'Add New User </br>';
                    if($dataform[name] && $dataform[name] != 0){
                        $rolename = $Contactusobj- 
            >getuserrolename($dataform[name]);
                        $description .= '<span>Role: 
              </span>'.$rolename.'</br>';
                    }
                    if($dataform[ministry_name] && $dataform[ministry_name] 
          != 0){
                        $ministryname = $Contactusobj- 
            >Getministryname($dataform[ministry_name]);
                        $description .= '<span>Ministry: 
             </span>'.$ministryname .'</br>';
                    }
                    if($dataform[statename] && $dataform[statename] != 0){
                        $statename = $Contactusobj- 
              >getuserstatename($dataform[statename]);
                        $description .= '<span>State: 
                </span>'.$statename.'</br>';
                    }
                    if($dataform[cityname] && $dataform[cityname] != 0){
                        $cityname = $Contactusobj- 
          >getdistrictname($dataform[cityname]);
                        $description .= '<span>City: 
          </span>'.$cityname.'</br>';
                    }
                    $description .= '<span>User Name: 
              </span>'.$dataform[username].'</br>';
                    $description .= '<span>First Name: 
           </span>'.$dataform[firstname].'</br>';
                    $description .= '<span>Last Name: 
             </span>'.$dataform[lastname].'</br>';
                    $description .= '<span>Email: 
          </span>'.$dataform[email].'</br>';
                    $description .= '<span>Mobile:</span>'.$dataform[mobile];
                    $auditlog = array("uid" => $userid->userid,
                                      "application_type" => 'User',
                                      "description" => $description
                                    );
                    $auditobj = new Application_Model_Auditlog;
                    $auditobj->insertauditlog($auditlog);
                    /***************audit log end by braj***************/
                    $mailObj = new Zend_Mail();

                    $username = $dataform['username'];

                    $fname = ucfirst($dataform['firstname']);
                    $weblink = WEB_LINK;
                    $body =   MESSAGE_BODY;
                    $body = str_replace('{user_name}',$username,$body);
                    $body = str_replace('{fname}',$fname,$body);
                    $body = 
           str_replace('{user_password}',$dataform['password'],$body);
                    $body = str_replace('{web_link}',$weblink,$body);
                    $subject= MAIL_SUBJECT;
                    $to     =$dataform['email'];
                    $from   =MAIL_FROM;
                    $name   = MAIL_NAME;
                    $mailObj->setSubject($subject);
                    $mailObj->setBodyHtml($body);
                    $mailObj->addTo($to, $name);
                    $mailObj->setFrom($from, 
           $name);//print_r($mailObj);die();
                    $mailObj->send();
                     
                    $this->_redirect('/user/add?actmsg=add');
                    }else{
                          if($countdata){
                            $this->view->assign('errorMessage', 'Your 
              username is already exists in the database.');
                            return;
                                } }}}}}}}
```

Model User.php

```
public function insertuserdetails($dataform) {
    $userid = new Zend_Session_Namespace('userid');
    $user_table = new Zend_Db_Table('dbt_users');
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $datainsert = "";
    $datainsert = array(
        'state'         => $dataform['statename'],
        //'cityname'=> $dataform['cityname'],
        'ministry_name' => $dataform['ministry_name'],
        'username'      => $dataform['username'],
        'password'      => hash_hmac('sha256', $dataform['password'], ''),
        'firstname'     => $dataform['firstname'],
        'lastname'      => $dataform['lastname'],
        'organisation'  => '',
        'mobile'        => $dataform['mobile'],
        'email'         => $dataform['email'],
        'telephone'     => '',
        'address'       => '',
        'role'          => $dataform['name'],
        'upload'        => '',
        'dateAdded'     => $date,
        'dateModify'    => $date,
        'status'        => 1,
        'created_by'    => $userid->userid,
        'login_time'    => 1,
        'tmp_password'  => md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)) . substr(md5($dataform['username']), 2, 10),
        'reset_time'    => $date
    );
    $insertdata = $user_table->insert($datainsert);

    return $insertdata;    }
```

Comment: You have posted a LOT of code... But which is actually relevant to your question? The provided code is "very confused" in it's implementation. The Model method insertuserdetails() is not called.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw when I debug code I come to know that controller function addAction(). Cant go inside in if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) condition because while debugging it is showing get[1] and post[] empty.

Comment: Can you provide details on how you are debugging this?

Comment: You will also need to provide the generated HTML from your form. Just the form section... I cannot tell from your code if you are including the name attribute in your form inputs.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I have added form code as required please note and help me out in this.

Comment: I had asked for the generated HTML for the Form but that isn't going to be helpful at all so don't worry about it. Are you using CodeIgniter or the Zend Framework or a mix of the two? You will have to debug what you get back from $this->getRequest() in addRequest and I still do not see how you are calling insertuserdetails(). So good luck with it

Comment: This might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363991/this-getrequest-ispost-return-false/23522331

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thanks for your reply please find updated code for insertuserdetails(). what i understand is here we used CodeIgniter as I am not a CodeIgniter developer it seems really hard to me.

Comment: about html form method ="post" is passing still form is not posting and not inserting data into database

Comment: In that case - you need to check the generated Form HTML and make sure your form fields have the "name" attribute. Without that you will not see any POST entries.